# Redirected Too Many Times on Apache2

Tags: server, apache2, websites

I'm using apache2 to host a website on Ubuntu Server. When I try to load the page from a browser, I get the "this page redirected you too many times" error. I don't have any duplicate files or anything that's redirecting the page. If anyone could help, it'd be very appreciated!

000-default.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot var/www/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr note
```

Comment: There is nothing in the virtual host configuration file that would cause a redirect. You will want to check whether there's something in your `.htaccess` file or in the files of the website to see where the redirect is happening. Looking at the information in `/var/log/apache2/access.log` (or `error.log`) may also provide a clue.

Comment: @matigo I don't have a `.htaccess` file and there's no errors in the `error.log` file either.

Comment: Do you use Cloudflare or any other proxy?